# Query to get all features within the circle postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I am trying to get all features which is within or intersect the circle of the given point when I am running the query I am getting all the features. Dont know what I am doing wrong. Here is my query:

> select postcode
> from ab
> where
> ST_DWithin(geom, ST_SetSRID(ST_MAKEPoint( -232855.14975877, 7787813.215242146  ), 27700), 5000 * 1609.34)

If i reduce the distance I am getting 0 response which is not possible. Any suggestions will be of great help

Answer (score 0):

You query looks fine, although I'm not sure you're providing a valid distance. The unit of EPSG:27700 is metre, so a radius of `5000 * 1609.34 = 8046700.00` metres is a lot to cover!

Perhaps this (5 miles):

```
SELECT postcode,
  ST_Distance(geom,
    ST_SetSRID(
      ST_MakePoint(-232855.14975877,7787813.215242146 ),27700))*0.000621371
FROM ab 
WHERE ST_DWithin(geom, 
  ST_SetSRID(
    ST_MakePoint(-232855.14975877,7787813.215242146),27700),5*1609.34);
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ddc992c1926568223fec3d15cd1e867e)